# excel userform shows in taskbar with delay (second activation)

Tags: excel, vba, taskbar, userform

I have an Excel Sheet with 6 Userforms that I want to be able to select and activate in the taskbar.

I used the following code, I found in another thread here:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim lFrmWndHdl As Long
Dim lStyle As Long

lFrmWndHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
lStyle = GetWindowLong(lFrmWndHdl, GWL_STYLE)
lStyle = lStyle Or WS_SYSMENU
lStyle = lStyle Or WS_MINIMIZEBOX
lStyle = lStyle Or WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
SetWindowLong lFrmWndHdl, GWL_STYLE, (lStyle)
lStyle = GetWindowLong(lFrmWndHdl, GWL_EXSTYLE)
lStyle = lStyle Or WS_EX_APPWINDOW
SetWindowLong lFrmWndHdl, GWL_EXSTYLE, lStyle
DrawMenuBar lFrmWndHdl
AppActivate ("Microsoft Excel")
ThisWorkbook.Application.Visible = False

End Sub
```

This works, but with delay.
When then first userform shows, there is no taskbar icon. After clicking a button and showing the second user form there are still no items. After closing the second userform and going back to the first, the icon for the first UF shows up.

I tried using some "DoEvents" between the lines, but that still didn't help.
All userforms are showmodal false.
It seems to need some sort of updating after the end sub.

Any Idea?